# jQuery - on() not working (Simple Example)

Tags: jquery, function, click

I'm having some trouble with my Jquery code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".upvote").on("click", function() 
            {
                alert('test');
            }
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black; color:white;">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="upvote" value=" + " />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. I checked and made sure I have jQuery 1.7. Can anyone help?

Comment: why not just use `.click(f);` or `.live("click",f);`?

Comment: `.on()` is the new `.bind()`/`.live()`/`.delegate()` as these three functions are now depreciated in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Whoever downvoted needs to rethink. It's not an interesting question but it's a valid one.

Comment: [Use](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/gE7XS/) a [proper](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) [IDE](http://netbeans.org/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing a closing `);` on your handler.  It's causing a syntax error which results in the code not running

```
$(".upvote").on("click", function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Yup. Also, if you do not want it to act as a regular submit button, you need to pass the event into the function and preventDefault() on it.

Comment: Oh my...this is embarassing. Well thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
$(".upvote").on("click", function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if you give

```
 $(".upvote").on("click", function() 
        {
            alert('test');
        });
```

instead of

```
 $(".upvote").on("click", function() 
        {
            alert('test');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code, otherwise it works find:

Change

```
        $(".upvote").on("click", function() 
        {
            alert('test');
        }
```

To:

```
        $(".upvote").on("click", function() 
        {
            alert('test');
        });//notice I had to add the `);` which closes the on function properly
```

Here is a jsfiddle of your code working with the small tweak: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/AVusC/